# IF function with several complexities

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

If the value is < 50 million, I need to display the first 3 characters of the last name. If the value is > 50 million, I need to display the first 4 characters of the first name.

So far I have this formula which is working but I don't know how to nest the LEFT function to display only the first 4 characters of the first name.

Can you help?

```
A1 = Last Name, First Name
A1 Example = Smith John
```

Formula:

```
=IF(B1<50000000,LEFT(A1,3), TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))), 1*LEN(A1)+1, LEN(A1))))
```

Comment: Your `A1` template has a comma delimiter which your `A1` example lacks. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=IF(B1<50000000,LEFT(A1,3),MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,4))
```

[image]

The above assumes a **single space** separator.

Comment: Thanks very much!! : )